# How to deal with multiple dots in a file name with Python pathlib?

Tags: python, windows, file, filesystems

I am having an issue with pathlib when I try to construct a file path that has a "." in its name, the pathlib module ignores it.

Here are example lines (I tried multiple versions, all resulted the same issue)

The issue is that the original file name will be coming from another application, so it is not like I can edit the name myself. I also do not want to do string replacement work arounds, if possible.

path=r"c:\temp"

## 1

`p=Path(path).joinpath("myfile.001").with_suffix(".bat")`

## 2

`p=Path(path, "myfile.001").with_suffix(".bat")`

## 3

`p=Path(path).with_name("myfile.001").with_suffix(".bat")`

All these lines will yield to

`WindowsPath('C:/temp/myfile.bat')`

So how do I make pathlib.Path to construct this full path properly. The final path has to be

`WindowsPath('C:/temp/myfile.001.bat')`

Not

`WindowsPath('C:/temp/myfile.bat')`

Naturally I am looking for a way to do it through `pathlib` itself, otherwise I can just use os.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling pathlib to replace the suffix `.001` with the suffix `.bat`. pathlib complies.

Tell pathlib to add `.bat` to the existing suffix.

```
p = Path(path, 'myfile.001')
p = p.with_suffix(p.suffix+'.001')
```

Comment: Do not get me wrong but how am I telling pathlib to replace a suffix with a suffix? Pathlib decides that ".001" is a suffix even when I use it with the .with_name("myfile.001") method. What is then the point of having .with_name and .with_suffix methods if it is not exclusively treating them as such.

Comment: @yaruncan: `with_suffix` tells pathlib to replace the existing suffix.

Comment: I see, I thought that was part of the construction way. I will take a look at it again.

Comment: Here is the thing, this makes it hard to guess what is going on with the incoming file name (not extension), it could be myfile.001.002.003.004 As you see none of those numbers are extensions. Because they are the names of possible duplicated objects (in Blender) Does it makes sense?

Comment: Also your proposed method can lead to names like this "myfile.001.002.003.bat.bat" if the actual name of the file used as an object name and in return used back in the python code with the text replacement. Anyway thanks for the suggestion, I will rethink this, maybe there is  abetter way

Comment: @yaruncan: Indeed, it can lead to such names. pathlib has no idea you want to treat `.bat` and `.001` differently. If you want to use your own concept of file extensions, you'll have to handle that yourself.